# How can I select records from yesterday's day from 6 AM to 6 AM of today

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `PD_HEAT_DATA` table with `HEATID` and `HEATDEPARTURE_ACT` columns. Data type of `HEATDEPARTURE` column is `VARCHAR2` and it holds timestamps in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`.

My requirement is to retrieve the records from `PD_HEAT_DATA` table between 6 AM of today and 6 AM of next day.

I have tried following code but it is not giving desired result:

```
select heatid, HEATDEPARTURE_ACT 
from pd_heat_data 
where HEATDEPARTURE_ACT between to_char(trunc(sysdate -1) + 6/24) 
                            and to_char(trunc (sysdate) + 6/24);
```

Datetime example:
HEATDEPARTURE_ACT
2019-07-23 23:11:11,359
2019-07-24 07:11:11,359

Comment: **NEVER**, ever, store DATE values in a `VARCHAR` column, just don't. Please fix your data model before you continue.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to convert date to strings for comparison.  But, you do want to convert the string to a date!

So just try this:

```
where to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= trunc(sysdate -1) + 6/24 and
      to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < trunc(sysate) + 6/24
```

That that this uses `>=` and `<` rather than `between`, because `between` includes both end points.

You can also phrase this using `interval` date arithmetic:

```
where to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '18' hour and
      to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < trunc(sysate) + interval '6' hour
```

Comment: tried query select heatid,HEATDEPARTURE_ACT from pd_heat_data where HEATDEPARTURE_ACT >= trunc(sysdate -1) + 6/24 and HEATDEPARTURE_ACT < trunc(sysdate) + 6/24; as you suggested but got following error- ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"

Comment: tried above but no avail. getting error- ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861. 00000 - "literal does not match format string"

Comment: getting error ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string" after trying select heatid,HEATDEPARTURE_ACT from pd_heat_data where  to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '18' hour and to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < trunc(sysdate) + interval '6' hour;

Comment: @deependra679 "date format picture ends before converting entire input string" suggests you have values that don't match 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'.

Comment: @deependra679 . . . This is the format that *you* specified in the question.  It does highlight why you don't want to store date time values as strings.